# Weak convergence of distribution family

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

I know the convergence in distribution and the weak convergence.
but I have two questions:

First one: does weak convergence implies pointwise convergence or it is the  same?

And second one: 
I have the following definition of weak convergence:
A sequence of distribution functions $(F_{n})_{_{n\geq 1}}$
converges weakly against a distribution function $F$ if $\lim_{n \to \infty}F_{n}(x)=F(x)$ for all continuity points of $F$.
My question:
What is if I want to show the weak convergence for a family of distribution functions:$(F_{t})_{_{t >0}}$ ($t$ is a real number)
i have two ideas: first one: i thought that i can choose $[t]=$greatest integer less than or equal to $t$, instead of $t$ . But if this is possible, i don't know why...

An my second idea, i show the weak convergence for all sequences $t_{n}$, which converge to $\infty$.

Thanks for your help

Comment: In the "first one": weak convergence and pointwise convergence of what? Cumulative distribution function?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes I`m talking about convergence of distribution functions.

Comment: If pointwise convergence means here that $F_n(x)$ converges to $F(x)$ for *any* $x$ then weak convergence does not in general implies pointwise convergence. It is not the same. Concerning the second question your second idea is okay.

Comment: But when i have a sequence of distribution functions $F_{n}(x)$ which converges to a distribution FunctionF for all continuity points of F, then we can talk about pointwise convergence? and when not, what type of convergence is it? thank you for your fast answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $F_{c}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\left[0,1\right]$ by $x\mapsto1$
if $x\geq c$ and $x\mapsto0$ otherwise.

If $c_{n}$ converges to
$c$ then $F_{c_{n}}$ converges to $F_{c}$ weakly. That is $F_{c_{n}}\left(x\right)\rightarrow F_{c}\left(x\right)$
for each $x\neq c$ (i.e. all continuity points of $F_{c}$)

Pointwise convergence is there if $F_{c_{n}}\left(x\right)\rightarrow F_{c}\left(x\right)$
for each $x$, so also for $x=c$.

However $F_{c_{n}}\left(c\right)\rightarrow F_{c}\left(c\right)=1$
askes for $c\geq c_{n}$ for $n$ large enough wich is not a consequence
of $c_{n}\rightarrow c$.

E.g if $F_{n^{-1}}$ converges weakly to $F_{0}$ while $F_{n^{-1}}\left(0\right)=0$
for each $n$ and $F_{0}\left(0\right)=1$. So there is no convergence
$F_{n^{-1}}\left(0\right)\rightarrow F_{0}\left(0\right)$.

---

**addendum**

Let $F$ be a CDF and denote $C:=\left\{ x\in\mathbb{R}\mid F\text{ is continuous at }x\right\} $.

A family $\left(F_{t}\right)_{t>0}$ of CDF's converges weakly to
$F$ under $t\rightarrow a$ if: $$\lim_{t\rightarrow a}F_{t}\left(x\right)=F\left(x\right)\text{ for each }x\in C$$

This is the case if and only $F_{t_{n}}$ converges weakly to $F$
for every sequence $\left(t_{n}\right)_{n}$ that converges to $a$.

Comment: okay thank you very much, i think it helps.

Comment: sorry but there is still a question.
In case of having a family of distribution functions
$F_{t}(x)$ and i try to show weak convergence for $t \to\ a$
which one is valid:
(i) $\lim_{t \to a}F_{t}(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}F_{t_{n}}(x)=F(x)$
(ii) $\lim_{t \to a}F_{t}(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}F_{t_{n}}(x)=F_{t}(x)$ for all sequences with $\lim_{n \to \infty}t_{n}=a$?

Comment: I have added something.